# MySQL ORDER BY takes a very long time even if I have indexes

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I have the following MySQL query which takes about 40 seconds on a linux VM:

```
SELECT
* FROM `clients_event_log`
WHERE
`ex_long` = 1475461 AND 
`type` in (2, 1) AND NOT 
(
    (category=1 AND error=-2147212542) OR
    (category=7 AND error=67)
)
    ORDER BY `ev_time` DESC LIMIT 100
```

The table has around 7 million rows, aprox. 800 MB in size and it has indexes on all the fields used in the WHERE and ORDER BY clauses.

Now if I change the query in such a way that the ordering is done in an outer SELECT, everything works much faster (around 100ms):

```
SELECT res.* FROM
(
  SELECT * FROM `clients_event_log`
  WHERE 
  `ex_long` = 1475461 AND 
  `type` in (2, 1) AND NOT 
  (
    (category=1 AND error=-2147212542) OR
    (category=7 AND error=67)
  )
) AS res
    ORDER BY res.ev_time DESC LIMIT 0, 100
```

Do you have any idea why the first query takes such a long time? Thank you.

---

Later Update:

1st Query EXPLAIN: 
[image]

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  clients_event_log   index   category,ex_long,type,error,categ_error ev_time 4   NULL    5636    Using where
```

2nd Query EXPLAIN:
[image]

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  system  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1   
2   DERIVED clients_event_log   ref category,ex_long,type,error,categ_error ex_long 5       131264  Using where
```

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `clients_event_log` (
  `ev_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `ev_time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `error` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ev_text` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userid` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ex_long` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_ex_long` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ex_text` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ev_id`),
  KEY `category` (`category`),
  KEY `ex_long` (`ex_long`),
  KEY `type` (`type`),
  KEY `ev_time` (`ev_time`),
  KEY `error` (`error`),
  KEY `categ_error` (`category`,`error`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Can you paste your index defintion  on `res.ev_time`

Comment: This shouldn't be the case of course. The queries are semantically equal and should lead to the same execution plan. As this is obviously not the case, I'd consider this a flaw in the DBMS.

Comment: also paste EXPLAIN output for both

Comment: You probably have single indexes on all the fields, e.g. one index on `ex_long`, one index on `type`, one index on `ev_time`. MySQL can only use one index per query, and is probably using the wrong one in your 1st query (e.g. the index on `ev_time`). Look at `explain` output to check that (and add it to your question). So to solve your problem, you would need a composite index, e.g. `ex_long, ev_time` (depending on your data, maybe other columns too) or force the correct single-column index (the one probably used in your 2nd query).

Comment: @Solarflare: I think the index would have to contain first all columns in `WHERE` and then all in `ORDER BY` to make MySQL use it for sorting. `create index idx_quick on clients_event_log(ex_long, type, error, category1, category7, ev_time);` However, the queries do exactly the same. It should make no difference that one query applies the `ORDER BY` directly and the other uses a fake subquery before applying it.

Comment: @Solarflare Thanks! that makes sense; I'll add a composite index

Comment: @TheGameiswar question updated. I'll rewrite the indexes. Thanks

Comment: please post explain as text

Comment: The first execution plan is plain stupid (access *every* record via an index only for the purpose of reading them in the order of the final sort.) As I said: a flaw in MySQL's optimizer.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner You are correct, it should not make a difference, but in MySQL, it does. This is the way in older mysql versions to create a derived table, and thus MyQSL will not use the now outer `order by`-index in the inner query. 5.7 will correctly execute it.

Comment: @Julian Your `explain` showed, as expected, that you use different indexes in your queries. You can either add the composite index (with as many columnsas  you want, but the 2 should be fine I guess), alternatively (or if it still does not work for some reason) you can force the correct index by using  `from \`clients_event_log\` force index (ex_long)` in your first query.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the second query (inner SELECT) because the MySQL optimiser decided to always use the `ev_time` index even if I tried multiple versions of a composite index containing the columns in the WHERE and ORDER BY clauses.

Using `force index (ex_long)` also worked.

The MySQL version was **5.5.38**

Thank you.

Comment: Just keep in mind that when you are updating to 5.7, this code might no longer do the trick. Your `limit` allows for the possibility that mysql chooses the index on `ev_time`, so it might do so again once the derived table will no longer be created with that syntax, so `force index` (either on the composite or the single index) would be the safer choice. Or try `optimize` on your table, your statistics might be off.

Answer (score 0):

Add these

```
INDEX(ev_long, ev_time),
INDEX(ev_long, type)
```

and use the first format of the query and let the optimizer decide which is better based on the statistics.